# Websocket server is a managed application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, websocket

I wish to have an embedded web socket server in my desktop application for communication with other applications.

From the research I've done, it would appear that in .NET 4.5 you can host a web socket server using IIS

Is it possible to host a web socket WCF service using something similar to `ServiceHost`, or does it have to be through IIS? (I am pretty new to WCF)

I did some other libraries that implemented the websocket spec but was hoping to use inbuilt .NET functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674271(v=vs.110).aspx
Your WCF service could be self hosted and communicate via WebSockets.

It work on Win 8 and .Net 4.5

Comment: Yes, as I said you can host WCF in your application. Look at the link, it contains full example for self hosted WCF service.

Comment: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll`. Yes, it requires IIS8

Comment: It requires Windows 8

Comment: Either way :) You cannot have IIS8 without W8. Still not sure it will work if you uninstall IIS8

Comment: @vtortola I haven't tried yet, but I expect the **C#** code sample here shows what I want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674273(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Ben I have tried, and I get that exception in Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

You will need Windows >= 8 or >= 2012 to use Microsoft WebSockets. If you do have any of those Windows versions, use it. Otherwise you can use:

- XSocket.NET: http://xsockets.net/
- SuperWebSocket : http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/
- Alchemy Websocket: http://alchemywebsockets.net/
- WebSocketListener : https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener

Cheers.